# MediaRouteHelper.buildMediaRouteSelector doesn't show me my chromecast when I send the app name parameter

Tags: chromecast

I have a weird situation, My app was working fine and I was able to select my chromecast device and see my receiver application without problem, so my chromecast is whitelisted.

Now my app doesn't work, the chromecast icon is disabled and I can't select my device.

Basically this line was working fine

mMediaRouteSelector = MediaRouteHelper.buildMediaRouteSelector(MediaRouteHelper.CATEGORY_CAST, getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), null);

but now it doesn't. Why? any ideas?

But this line works fine:

MediaRouteHelper.buildMediaRouteSelector( MediaRouteHelper.CATEGORY_CAST)

Of course I can't see the receiver app (html).

I am thinking maybe my chromecast is not whitelisted, just like the beginning when I started with the development.

Any ideas?

Is there a way to check if my chromecast is whitelisted or not?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you access your Chromecast device through your Chrome browser via:

http://[IP address of your Chromecast device]:9222?

If yes, then the device has been successfully whitelisted.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the "Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for updates" option is checked in the Chromecast setup.  This option gets cleared if you do a factory data reset.